# XSLT Number test

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I am having a problem where the value of the $current variable came in as '6E144270003'.  My original goal was to just test for a number, but '6E144270003' passed the number() test because it is a valid 'scientific notation' (as was pointed out to me here).

I need a valid test to allow data containing only integers (can include the decimal and minus sign) to equate to true and any other data to equate to false.

Should pass: 1234567890
Should pass: 123.45
Should pass: 123.5
Should pass: -123.45

```
 <xsl:if test="number($current) = number($current)">  
    <xsl:value-of select="$current"/>   
 </xsl:if>
```

Comment: @joncar: Please, learn the ethics of asking questions. Never change your question to make accepted and upvoted answers seem incorrect! Better, ask a new question.

Comment: @joncar: Your examples are decimals, not "data containing only integers, as you say in the question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am having a problem where the value
>   of the $current variable came in as
>   '6E144270003' and it failed in the
>   Saxon 2.0 processor with an error of
>   'Cast failed, invalid lexical value -
>   xs:double'.

I cannot repro this problem.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:variable name="current" select="'6E144270003'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="number($current) = number($current)">
    <xsl:value-of select="$current"/>
 </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when run with SAXON 9.0.0.4, produces**:

```
6E144270003
```

> I'm unsure why this happened when it
>   is not a number and also how to
>   correct it. Basically if it is not a
>   number I don't want to output it

**The string `"6E144270003"` *can* be used as a number in XPath 2.0**, because in XPath 2.0 the so called *scientific notation` is a valid way to represent a number.

This is one interesting example where the behavior of XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 is different.

**UPDATE**: The OP has indicated that he wants a test that will evaluate to `false()` if the string contains anything but digits.

This can be achieved best by a regular expression, or even:

```
translate($s, '0123456789', '') eq ''
```

**UPDATE2**: The OP changed his question again!!!

For the latest question here is the answer:

**Use**:

```
$s castable as xs:decimal
```

**This transformation demonstrates the correctness of this method:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select=
      "for $s in ('1234567890',
                 '123.45',
                 '123.5',
                '-123.45',
                 '6E144270003'
                 )
       return
         if($s castable as xs:decimal)
           then $s
           else ()

      "/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the correct result is produced**:

```
1234567890 123.45 123.5 -123.45
```

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 fast answer. Also this is the same for me. I think it should point out that this is not the proper data type test in XSLT 2.0. The OP should use 'castable' operator.

Comment: @Alejandro: `castable` is useful to test if some `item()` is of a certain type. If the OP is just interested if a value *can be represented and used as a number* then `number($x) = number($x)` is still a good test.

Comment: In this case the data will not ever be represented as a 'scientific notation'.  I need the IF condition in this case to fail due to the 'E'.

Comment: @jonkar: This is even a valid integer! So, please, update your question and say that you want to test that all characters of the string are digits!

Comment: @jonkar: I updated my answer, giving you a solution that you probably want.

Comment: @jonkar: I updated my answer for a second time to answer your *new* question!!! Please, don't change your question!!!  `ASK NEW QUESTIONS !!!`

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks, I edited my answer -- we might ask SO to automatically downvote questions that change more than twice.

Comment: I am sorry Dimitre and Alejandro, I edited my question because I thought that was what Dimitri was asking me several comments up.  I do appreciate your patience and guidance and will strive to get it right next time.

Comment: 14 years later, in Saxon 12.4: now number($x) throws an exception when the value cannot be cast to a number, e.g. `number("Banana")`

Comment: This is definitely a bug. Even in the latest 4.0 F&O Spec the rules haven't been changed: https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xpath-functions-40/Overview.html#func-number . It says: "If $value is the empty sequence or if $value cannot be converted to an xs:double, the xs:double value NaN is returned." Probably needs to be reported to Saxonica (@MichaelKay @user:415448)